# Error in doctrine query : Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

Hello i have an entity with two primary keys .

```
class UsefulnessEvaluation
{
  /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\EvaluationBundle\Entity\Evaluation", cascade={"persist","remove"})
    */
    private $evaluation;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist","remove"})
    */
    private $user;

     /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdAt;
//etc
}
```

I want , in repository , count the number of an evaluation:

```
class UsefulnessEvaluationRepository extends EntityRepository
{

  public function countEvaluationLikes($evaluation_id)
  {   
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
         'SELECT count(p.evaluation) as nbre
          FROM AppEvaluationBundle:UsefulnessEvaluation p
          WHERE p.evaluation = :id

         )->setParameter('id', $evaluation_id);
      return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
  }

}
```

this is the error :

> Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query is not
>   supported. You should split the parameter into the explicit fields and
>   bind them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're selecting `count(p.evaluation)` but since you're already specifying the id of p.evaluation it seems unnecessary because you're guaranteed to get non-null values for p.evaluation.

Try this

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT count(p) as nbre
    FROM AppEvaluationBundle:UsefulnessEvaluation p
    WHERE IDENTITY(p.evaluation) = :id'    
    )->setParameter('id', $evaluation_id);
```